# Changing the color of the switch in QML

Tags: qt, qml

I want the color to be green when the switch is on and red when it is off. I also want to write "On" in it when the switch is on and "Off" when it is off. How can I do it? Currently, my code is as follows:

```
 Rectangle{
        border.width: 2
        border.color: "black"
        id:rectangle_gps_l1_deger
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        Layout.preferredWidth: mainWindow.width/8
        Layout.preferredHeight: mainWindow.height/22
        Layout.margins: -3
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        color:row_even
        ColumnLayout {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            Switch {
                id:switch_rectangle_gps_l1_deger
                text: qsTr("")
                Material.accent: Material.Green

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Giving size and color to the switch, writing On-Off inside it, in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443540/giving-size-and-color-to-the-switch-writing-on-off-inside-it-in-qml)

Comment: Do not repost the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73443540/giving-size-and-color-to-the-switch-writing-on-off-inside-it-in-qml#comment129711211_73443540) more than once.

Comment: ok i deleted the other one

Comment: Please read the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-switch) for customizing a Switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check its **state** by using `if and else`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Switch")

    Switch {
        id: switch1
        x: 272
        y: 200
        width: 101

        text: qsTr("off")
        Material.accent: Material.Green

        onToggled:
        {
            if(checked)
            {
                switch1.text= qsTr("on")

            }
            else
            {
                switch1.text= qsTr("off")

            }

        }

    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have one more question. How can I change the colors of "on" and "off" texts.

Comment: @MertTurfan , l check this,  it depends on your qt version because in qt 6 some options where deleted . One way is you create your custom switch, other way is using `palette`. `palette {button: checked ? "green" : red }`

Comment: You can use `style:switchStyle` and change it like this [example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-switchstyle.html) or use [this document](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-switch)